# Steps involved in query execution

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, greatest-n-per-group

Consider the following table:

```
name     salary
-----   --------
a       100
b       200
c       300
d       300   -- note the duplicate max
```

Now we want to calculate second maximum salary using the following query:

```
SELECT max(salary)
FROM emptable
WHERE salary < (SELECT max(salary)
                FROM emptable);
```

So how will MySQL determine the result of this query? For example, what I assume is that first it will execute the sub query in the `where` clause and determine the max salary, call it `M1` (which will be `400`) and store it in some variable. Then it will find max salary from the original table which will be `400`, but won't satisfy the the constraint in the `where` clause (i.e., compare it with `M1`). Now it will make a copy of the original table with tuple containing this(`400`) value removed as it didn't satisfy the constraint and repeat this process till it finds the desired result.

Most probably I am wrong, but I wrote the above process just to clarify my question.

Comment: What is the desired result if there's a tie for first?

Comment: Solves the query, but not the Question:  `SELECT salary FROM emptable ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1, 1;`

Comment: @RickJames `"Solves the query, but not the Question: SELECT salary FROM emptable ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1, 1;"` Nope, for data `a 100, b 200,c 300,d 300` you will get 300 not 200. **[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=41c818f4822aa4a3c770e0ecda99c796)**

Comment: @LukaszSzozda - Aha, the problem statement was not precise enough!  I edited your Question.

Comment: @RickJames Actually it is not my question. And I am not sure that OP wanted to edit it that way.

Comment: @shiva -- Which do you want?  Ranking or Dense ranking?

Comment: @RickJames Sorry for the late response. Any ranking would work fine, all I wanted to know the way sql executes it on the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery appearing in the `WHERE` clause is not correlated to the outer query, so most likely the optimizer will compute it once, and then cache the result somewhere.  After this, the max value will be used to filter off one or more records having that max value.  And then it is just a typical max query.  To confirm this, or to find something maybe that I missed, you may run `EXPLAIN` on your query.

By the way, you can also write this query using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT salary
FROM emptable
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 1
OFFSET 1;
```

This should also return the salary ranked second highest (i.e. is robust to there being more than one of the same salary).  But this approach makes it easy to find any rank of the salary, whereas the subquery approach does not extend well.

Comment: Thanks. I never heard of `explain` before, I will have to read on that and from a quick view it seems it will take me some time to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Query optimizer is free to do any optimization(based on indexes/data distibution/...). You should always check actual execution plan:

```
explain
SELECT max(salary)
FROM emptable
WHERE salary < (SELECT max(salary)
                FROM emptable);
```

Output:

```
┌────┬─────────────┬──────────┬──────┬───────────────┬──────┬─────────┬──────┬──────┬─────────────┐
│ id │ select_type │  table   │ type │ possible_keys │ key  │ key_len │ ref  │ rows │    Extra    │
├────┼─────────────┼──────────┼──────┼───────────────┼──────┼─────────┼──────┼──────┼─────────────┤
│  1 │ PRIMARY     │ emptable │ ALL  │ null          │ null │ null    │ null │    4 │ Using where │
│  2 │ SUBQUERY    │ emptable │ ALL  │ null          │ null │ null    │ null │    4 │             │
└────┴─────────────┴──────────┴──────┴───────────────┴──────┴─────────┴──────┴──────┴─────────────┘
```

And with `INDEX` on salary:

```
create index idx ON emptable(salary);

┌────┬─────────────┬───────┬──────┬───────────────┬──────┬─────────┬──────┬──────┬──────────────────────────────┐
│ id │ select_type │ table │ type │ possible_keys │ key  │ key_len │ ref  │ rows │            Extra             │
├────┼─────────────┼───────┼──────┼───────────────┼──────┼─────────┼──────┼──────┼──────────────────────────────┤
│  1 │ PRIMARY     │ null  │ null │ null          │ null │ null    │ null │ null │ Select tables optimized away │
│  2 │ SUBQUERY    │ null  │ null │ null          │ null │ null    │ null │ null │ Select tables optimized away │
└────┴─────────────┴───────┴──────┴───────────────┴──────┴─────────┴──────┴──────┴──────────────────────────────┘
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=82b04d6dd1c5e89bf02204fbffa7ca34)**

Comment: Inadequate answer -- it does not include `name`.  Adding such may make a big difference in the `EXPLAINs`.

Comment: @RickJames Inadequate comment. Please check OP's original question. There is no mention about name/grouping by name/or selecting entire row. OP wants only to get the second highest salary (single value) only. I agree that adding new column will change query plan, but it is not part of question.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Thanks. I never heard of `explain` before, so will have to read up on that.

Answer (score 0):

You want "dense ranking".

The following formulation *may* be better optimized, hence faster if you have a large table:

```
SELECT salary
    FROM emptable
    WHERE salary < (SELECT max(salary)
                    FROM emptable)
    ORDER BY salary DESC
    LIMIT 1,1;
```

It would need

```
INDEX(salary)
```